# Назначение и использование блоков потоков данных в TPL

Tags: c#, tpl-dataflow

Для чего предназначены и как используются на практике блоки, указанные в [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx) ? Реальзуют ли они модель акторов и каким образом?

Comment: Судя по документации,— да, реализуют _«The System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow namespace provides an actor-based programming model that supports in-process message passing for coarse-grained dataflow and pipelining tasks.»_ А что, есть сомнения? Там также есть примеры, что в них Вам не понятно?